# The tags page incorrectly shortens tag excerpts

Tags: bug, tags, tag-wiki-excerpt, tags-page

On the Christianity site there are a few tags relating to history. It was decided that the church-history tag should be used when applicable rather than the generic history tag. So [it has the excerpt](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history):

> Use the church-history tag for questions about the history of the church, from the time of Acts to the present.

The [tags page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tags) shortens this to:

> for questions about the history of the church, from the time of Acts to the present.

Which is the complete opposite of what we want. Why does it incorrectly shorten them this way?

Comment: It reads fine on that page, though.

Comment: Regardless of excerpt truncation, you should really start with a description of when to use the `history` tag. It's confusing to readers too: when I first read your question, I though “questions about the history of the church …” was the intent of the tag in question, and I'm sure I'm not the only one. And add a word like “instead” in the sentence about some other tag.